# Elasticsearch partial bulk update

Tags: php, json, elasticsearch, bigdata, bulk

I have `6k` of data to update in **ElasticSearch**. And I have to use `PHP`.
I search in the documentation and I have found this, [Bulk Indexing](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/_indexing_documents.html#_bulk_indexing) but this is not keeping the previous data.

I have structure:

```
[
  {
    'name': 'Jonatahn',
    'age' : 21
  }
]
```

My code snippet to update:

```
$params =[
    "index" => "customer",
    "type" => "doc",
    "body" => [
        [
            "index" => [
                "_index" => "customer",
                "_type" => "doc",
                "_id" => "09310451939"
            ]
        ],
        [
            "name" => "Jonathan"
        ]
    ]
];

$client->bulk($params);
```

When I send `['name' => 'Jonathan']`  I expect the `name` will be updated and keep the `age`, but the `age` gets deleted.
Sure, I still can update data-by-data but this will take a long time, is there any better way to do that?

Answer (score 12):

My error was to using `"index"`, but the correct way to do what I want, was `"update"`.

The final code is:

```
$params =[
"index" => "customer",
"type" => "doc",
"body" => [
    [
        "update" => [
    //   ^^^^^^ Here I change from index to update
            "_index" => "customer",
            "_type" => "doc",
            "_id" => "09310451939"
        ]
    ],
    [
        "doc" => [
            "name" => "Jonathan"
        ]
    ]
]
];

$client->bulk($params);
```

Using the code above, my data keep previous data and just update the data I passing in params.

Response:

```
Array
(
    [took] => 7
    [timed_out] =>
    [_shards] => Array
        (
            [total] => 5
            [successful] => 5
            [skipped] => 0
            [failed] => 0
        )

    [hits] => Array
        (
            [total] => 1
            [max_score] => 1
            [hits] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [_index] => customer
                            [_type] => doc
                            [_id] => 09310451939
                            [_score] => 1
                            [_source] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => Jonathan
                                    [age] => 23
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 4):

As per [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/docs-bulk.html), Bulk API possible actions are index, create, delete and `update`. `update` expects that the partial doc, upsert and script and its options are specified on the next line.

```
POST _bulk
{ "update" : {"_id" : "1", "_type" : "_doc", "_index" : "test"} }
{ "doc" : {"field2" : "value2"} }
```

Comment: how can i do this using PHP ? i used above answer's code and not all documents are being updated, any clue ? thanks, here is my issue https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php/issues/785

Answer (score 3):

Here is my final code.

```
<?php

require_once('../elasticsearch.php');

//initialize elasticsearch
$params = array();

$params['index'] = $elastcsearch_index;
$params['type']  = $elastcsearch_type;

///////////////////////////////////////////////////
//update seeders n leechers in elasticsearch 

//get updated records
$get_updated_records = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT content_id, seeders, leechers FROM content WHERE is_updated = '1' order by seeders DESC") ;

//create blank array
$results = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_updated_records)){
    //put all results in array
    $results[] = $row;

}   

//from https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/_indexing_documents.html

$params = ['body' => []];

for($i = 0; $i < count($results); $i++) {

    $params["body"][]= [
            "update" => [
                "_index" => $elastcsearch_index,
                "_type" => $elastcsearch_type,
                "_id" => $results[$i]['content_id']
            ]
        ];

    $params["body"][]= [
            "doc" => [
                "seeders" => intval($results[$i]['seeders']) ,
                "leechers" => intval($results[$i]['leechers']) ,
            ]
        ];

    // Every 1000 documents stop and send the bulk request
     if ($i % 1000 == 0) {
        $responses = $elasticsearch->bulk($params);

        // erase the old bulk request
        $params = ['body' => []];

        // unset the bulk response when you are done to save memory
        unset($responses);
    } 
}

// Send the last batch if it exists
if (!empty($params['body'])) {
    $responses = $elasticsearch->bulk($params);
}
```

Comment: Actually `_type` is deprecated now. You don't need to add it anymore. Default document type will be used instead

Answer (score 0):

`$batch_elastics` is array of result
i just unset this two value from row each time....
because I don't need this value in insert or update

```
unset($batch_row['type']);

unset($batch_row['diamonds_id']);
```

code start from here...

```
    if(count($batch_elastics)){
        // echo 'hi';die;
        $params = array();                
        $params = ['body' => []]; 
        $i=1;       
        foreach($batch_elastics as $batch_row){
            $type=$batch_row['type'];
            $id=$batch_row['diamonds_id'];
            unset($batch_row['type']);
            unset($batch_row['diamonds_id']); 
            if($type=="create"){                                    
                $params["body"][]= [
                        "create" => [
                            "_index" => 'diamonds',                                                        
                            "_id" => $id,
                        ]
                    ];        
                    $params["body"][]= $batch_row;                             
                if ($i % 1000 == 0) {
                    $responses = $client->bulk($params);                                
                    $params = ['body' => []];                                
                    unset($responses);
                }
            } 
            $i=$i+1;
        }
        
        // Send the last batch if it exists
        if (!empty($params['body'])) {
            $responses = $client->bulk($params);
        }
        $params = array();                
        $params = ['body' => []]; 
        $i=1; 
        foreach($batch_elastics as $batch_row){
            $type=$batch_row['type'];
            $id=$batch_row['diamonds_id'];
            unset($batch_row['type']);
            unset($batch_row['diamonds_id']); 
            if($type=="update"){                                    
                $params["body"][]= [
                        "update" => [
                            "_index" => 'diamonds',                                                        
                            "_id" => $id,
                        ]
                    ];        
                $params["body"][]= [
                    "doc"=>$batch_row
                ];                           
                if ($i % 1000 == 0) {
                    $responses = $client->bulk($params);                                
                    $params = ['body' => []];                                
                    unset($responses);
                }
            } 
            $i=$i+1;
        }
        
        // Send the last batch if it exists
        if (!empty($params['body'])) {
            $responses = $client->bulk($params);
        }
    }
```